# Adding buttons to an array / dictionary in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, ios6, appdelegate

I'm a total noob with objective C, so any help/explanations would be massively appreciated!

I'm making a drum app for a bit of fun. I have a button set for each part of the drum, and when the button is tapped, it is animated to grow. I've created the buttons on the storyboard, and not in code.

I've got the buttons to animate, but I don't want to repeat the code for every element of the drum kit, but I'm having some trouble with assigning buttons to an array, deciding the button pressed (with tags??), and then causing that button to animate.

Here's some of my code to help:

```
@interface mainViewController : UIViewController
//set buttons 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;

- (IBAction)buttonTrigger:(UIButton *)sender;
```

I won't add the code for every single button as it's the same:

```
@interface mainViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) CGAffineTransform button1transform, button2transform;;

@end

@implementation mainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.button1 addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"highlighted" options:0 context:0];
    self.button1transform = self.button1.transform;

    [self.button1 addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"highlighted" options:0 context:0];
    self.button2transform = self.button2.transform;
}
```

//animations:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{   
    if (object == self.button1)
    {

        CGAffineTransform transform;

        if (self.button1.isHighlighted)
        { 
            float scale = 2.0;
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.button1transform, scale, scale);
        }
        else
        {
            transform = self.button1transform;
        }

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                              delay:0.5
                            options:options
                         animations:^{
            self.button1.transform = transform;
        }
                         completion:nil];
    }

    //this code is repeated for the other 6 buttons
}


- (void)dealloc
{
    [self.button1 removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"highlighted"];

    [self.button2 removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"highlighted"];
}
```

Some help with adding buttons to arrays would be great

Thanks

Comment: Sidenote: You can't use KVO on a button's "highlighted" state. Subclass the button and override `setHighlighted:` instead.

Comment: Rolled back, please don't go deleting the text from the question so it doesn't make sense. If you don't want people to see your code don't bother asking a question.

Comment: I've already rolled back once please stop changing your question to not make sense, like I've already said if you don't want people to know your code don't ask a question, it really is that simple.

Comment: @Popeye im simply tidying up the code so it's less code but gets my question across in a more easily readable way, what on earth is wrong with that?

Comment: Clearly you didn't do that though checking the edit history you have radically changed the question for not to make any sense for the answers given that have solved the problem so in turn those no long solve the original question asked.

Answer (score 1):

Use IBOutletCollection to link all the buttons using interface(storyboard)

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *allButtons;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *transformArray;

-(IBAction) buttonsHighlighted:(id)sender;
-(IBAction) buttonsNormalState:(id)sender;
```

[image]

[image]

Then attach IBAction method with all the buttons. I think you will need two methods (one for highlighted state and one for the normal state). You can choose the appropriate method actions from the list

[image]

Tag each button appropriately. Then add all the transform objects into an array according to tag

```
 //add according to tag
self.transformArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(self.snareButtonTransform), nil];
```

after that do something like this

```
-(IBAction) buttonsHighlighted:(id)sender
{
    for(UIButton *btn in self.allButtons)
    {
        NSLog(@"Btn Tag: %d", btn.tag); //You can get the tag by this and do appopriate action if needed

        //allow button to be pressed during animation stage
        UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState |
        UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction;

        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformFromString([transformArray objectAtIndex:btn.tag]);

        if(btn.isHighlighted)
        {   //suble growth, pulse like
            float scale = 1.05;
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scale, scale);
        }
        else
        {
            //transform = self.snareButtonTransform;
        }
        //fast animation, represents fast drum hit
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.025
                              delay:0.0
                            options:options
                         animations:^{
                             btn.transform = transform;
                         }
                         completion:nil];

    }
}
```

Then in `-(IBAction) buttonsNormalState:(id)sender;` method just reset the transform for each of the button or for the button whose scale is large.

```
-(IBAction) buttonsNormalState:(id)sender
{
    for(UIButton *btn in self.allButtons)
    {
        NSLog(@"Btn Tag: %d", btn.tag); //You can get the tag by this and do appopriate action if needed

        //allow button to be pressed during animation stage
        UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState |
        UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction;

        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformFromString([transformArray objectAtIndex:btn.tag]);

        //fast animation, represents fast drum hit
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.025
                              delay:0.0
                            options:options
                         animations:^{
                             btn.transform = transform;
                         }
                         completion:nil];
    }
}
```

**For scenario as described in comment**

Please check this if you want to do it using only one method/action (if it is according to the scenario I described in the comment section). Only attach method using Touch Up Inside and then

```
-(IBAction) buttonsHighlighted:(id)sender
{
    for(UIButton *btn in self.allButtons)
    {
        NSLog(@"Btn Tag: %d", btn.tag); //You can get the tag by this and do appopriate action if needed

        //allow button to be pressed during animation stage
        UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState |
        UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction;

        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformFromString([transformArray objectAtIndex:btn.tag]);
        CGAffineTransform originalTranform = transform;

        if(btn.isHighlighted)
        {   //suble growth, pulse like
            float scale = 1.05;
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scale, scale);
        }
        else
        {
            //transform = self.snareButtonTransform;
        }
        //fast animation, represents fast drum hit
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.025
                              delay:0.0
                            options:options
                         animations:^{
                             btn.transform = transform;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                             [UIView animateWithDuration:0.025
                                                   delay:0.0
                                                 options:options
                                              animations:^{
                                                  btn.transform = originalTranform;
                                              }
                                              completion:nil];

                         }];

    }
}
```

**Update**

In ViewDidLoad method or whenever you have assigned values to your transforms, add them to the transformArray

```
self.transformArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(self.snareButtonTransform),
                       NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(self.snareButtonTransform2),
                       NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(self.snareButtonTransform3),
                       NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(self.snareButtonTransform4),
                       NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(self.snareButtonTransform5),
                       NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(self.snareButtonTransform6),
                       nil];
```

**New Code**

```
-(IBAction) buttonsHighlighted:(id)sender
{
    for(UIButton *btn in self.allButtons)
    {
        NSLog(@"Btn Tag: %d", btn.tag); //You can get the tag by this and do appopriate action if needed

        //allow button to be pressed during animation stage
        UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState |
        UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction;

        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformFromString([transformArray objectAtIndex:btn.tag]);

        if(btn.isHighlighted)
        {   //suble growth, pulse like
            float scale = 1.05;
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scale, scale);
        }
        else
        {
            //transform = self.snareButtonTransform;
        }
        //fast animation, represents fast drum hit
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.025
                              delay:0.0
                            options:options
                         animations:^{
                             btn.transform = transform;
                         }
                         completion:nil];

    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use comments for an extended debug session. If you want to contact each other and communicate that way, that's great -- but this isn't what they're used for.

Comment: I am just about to check it. Couldn't check it yesterday, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code. No need for the transformArray or Collection outlets or the transform variables that you created. Please check it gives you the desired result.

```
-(IBAction) buttonsHighlighted:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;

    NSLog(@"Btn Tag: %d", btn.tag);

    UIViewAnimationOptions options = UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState |
    UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction;


    CGAffineTransform transform = btn.transform;

    float scale = 1.0;

    if(btn.isHighlighted)
    {
        //suble growth, pulse like
        scale = 1.05;
    }

    transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scale, scale);

    //fast animation, represents fast drum hit
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.025
                          delay:0.0
                        options:options
                     animations:^{
                         btn.transform = transform;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.025
                                               delay:0.0
                                             options:options
                                          animations:^{
                                              btn.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, 1.0);
                                          }
                                          completion:nil];

                     }];

}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of adding another answer???? You have already provided and answer please just update that one using the `Edit` feature -1

Comment: @Popeye This answer is based on a very different strategy, so to avoid confusion I added a new answer. If you look at the previous answer, it has a lot of code already. So, I added a new answer for simplicity. I think there is no rule that stops me from doing so, otherwise stackoverflow would have it in place as a policy.

Comment: That's not the way this works you should just add to your existing answer, all this looks like is you trying to gain additional points -1 remains

Comment: think whatever you want to think. You should not pass judgments on what the other person is thinking or not. I don't care about -1, make it -1000 and i will still not care. But don't pass your judgments on what someone is thinking or not.

Comment: This isn't passing judgement this is advising your doing the wrong thing. There is an edit button for a reason and you should use it not provide another answer. If you want my judgement this doesn't add to the your other answer and seems pointless. This answer fails to explain itself which answers should, so if your going to provide another answer the least you could do is provided a better one then your first answer. So again this answer seems absolutely pointless, and by the way the up and down votes and comments are here for us to pass judgement. If you don't like it don't answer or ask

Comment: Though I respect your suggestion that I should have edit it, your judgement was uncalled for. If you read your comment again you will see it again. And for your information, this example did solve it for the person (I took time to chat with him on fb to solve it). The answer may be pointless for you but it wasn't for the person who needed it. And I agree with you about up and down vote, but I was only pointing out your suggestion that I did it to gain extra point. So, if you can't see what I am talking about then its pointless to talk to you.

Comment: Lets put it this way, you have actually followed the rules and if you had just edited you first answer you would have got an upvote from me but you didn't. If you have spent time on fb discussing it then you must have a better explanation then you have put. The way Stackoverflow works is it's not just there to help the person asking the question it is there to help people having the same issue in the future so if you don't explain your answer then no one will understand it in the future, this is what makes your first answer a lot better then your second because it explains itself well.

Comment: ok, friend. Lets leave it there. Thanks for your time. I will try to keep that in mind.